# Disable MathJax in one post on Blogger.com

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I have successfully added the MathJax javascript below in the the Blogger's theme, which apply to every post in the blog, but not the whole page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

However, I had some post in which I want MathJax to be disabled, so I can type double dollar sign. How should I do it? 
Besides, Are there an escapes for the dollar sign, backslash , and square brackets in MathJax?

Comment: You want to disable and enable MathJax on the same page?

Comment: Just disable it in one post, because MathJax had been enables in every post. Thanks.

Comment: Read the last paragraph in this section of the documentation  http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-in-html-documents